# android volume gain AudioTrack DatagramPacket

Tags: java, android, audio, packet

I need help to apply a volume gain on audio stream to increase the volume output of device.

Here is some code of my app:

```
private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 8000; // Hertz
private static final int BUF_SIZE = 372; //Bytes
```

...

```
AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, BUF_SIZE, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

...

```
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, BUF_SIZE);
socket.receive(packet);
```

...

```
track.write(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
```

Someone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're giving very little information. Please let us know what you already tried and didn't work.

Comment: i tried to use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23035448/4697571 but the sound is very bad. I didn't found other solution. That's why I post on stackoverflow.

Comment: did you find a solution?